# Zoom drawing like a map in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, zooming, mxml

I am trying to zoom my drawing like a map in flex, but all what i've done it's zooming by HSlider. Can you explain me how to zoom my drawing like a google map?

Here's my code for zooming:
My zooming functions:

```
private function doZoom(component:UIComponent,val:Number):void
        {
            if(component is Container)
            {
                var children:Array = Container(component).getChildren();
                for(var i:int = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                {
                    zoomChildren(children[i], val);
                }
            }

        }

        private function zoomChildren(component:UIComponent,val:Number):void
        {

            component.scaleX = val;
            component.scaleY = val;
            if(component is Container) 
            {
                var children:Array = Container(component).getChildren();
                for(var i:int = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                {
                    doZoom(children[i], val);
                }
            }
        }

        public function applyZoom():void
        {

            if(pnl == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            doZoom(pnl,zoomSlider.value);
        }
```

and my components:

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:Button  label="Загрузить SVG" click="PathsService.getPaths()"/>  

    <mx:Panel  y="30" width="1300" height="600" id="pnl"  title="Отрисовка SVG" borderColor="#008040" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="13">

        <s:VGroup height="100%" width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

            <s:SpriteVisualElement width="100%" height="100%" id="spr" />
        </s:VGroup>

    </mx:Panel>
    <s:HGroup height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:Label text="Zoom" x="250"/>

        <mx:HSlider id="zoomSlider" minimum=".1" value="1"
                    maximum="2" change="applyZoom()" width="180" x="300"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to make the component respond based on mouse scroll wheel input you should register an event listener for the mouse scroll event.

for example on the component that you are trying to zoom add the following line
    `addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, mouseWheelHandler);`

in your mouseWheelHandler function you should get the event.delta value which should contain the amount the scroll wheel has moved